# Entrada única no formulário asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Tenho um código que faz o cadastro de certo tipos de equipamento, os campos de formulário que tenho são: Nome, Servidor, Tipo e Porta do equipamento.

Gostaria que não fosse possível o usuário cadastrar dois equipamentos com a mesma porta e não sei como fazer.

Meu código asp.net é:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/interna.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="equipamentocadastro.aspx.cs" Inherits="usuariocadastro" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderCorpo" Runat="Server">
                                                <div class="tabbable">
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs padding-16">

                                                        <li class="active">
                                                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#edit-password" aria-expanded="true">
                                                                <i class="blue ace-icon fa fa-tachometer bigger-125"></i>
                                                                Cadastro de equipamentos
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
    <br />
     <div>


         <!--///////////////////////////// problema após colocar o CssClass que permite a busca dentro da dropdownlist-->


         <!--script src="assets/css/chosen.css"></!--script>
         <script src="assets/js/chosen.jquery.js"></script-->


         <p>Cadastre os MPNs que serão monitorados.</p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td class="td">Nome:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocalizacao" runat="server" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblIDEquipamento" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </td>

        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td">Servidor:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlServidor"  Runat="Server">
                         <asp:ListItem Value="1">192.168.0.21</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="2">192.168.0.28</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="3">192.168.0.200</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                 </div> 

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="td">Tipo:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTipoEqp"  Runat="Server">
                         <asp:ListItem Value="1">MPN</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="2">Graxeira</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                 </div> 
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td">Porta:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPorta" runat="server" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td class="td">Enviar alerta por e-mail:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnviarMensagem" runat="server" class="ace ace-switch ace-switch-3"  />
            </td>
        </tr>       


        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Atualizar" Visible="false" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancelar" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 10px; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
        <p>
            Total de usuários: <asp:Label ID="lbltotalcount" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        </p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewEmail" runat="server" DataKeyNames="IDEquipamento" autogeneratecolumns="false"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewEmail_SelectedIndexChanged"
OnRowDeleting="GridViewEmail_RowDeleting" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:boundfield datafield="Localizacao" headertext="Nome"  />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="Endereco" headertext="Servidor"  />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="NomeTipoEquipamento" headertext="Tipo Equipamento"  />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="Porta" headertext="Porta"  />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="EnviarMensagem" headertext="Enviar alerta"  />
                <asp:commandfield showdeletebutton="true" buttontype="Image" deleteimageurl="~\images\lixo.png" headertext=" Excluir "  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </Columns>

            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"  />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White"  />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"  />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>    
     </div>
    <br /><br />
            <div style="float:left;">
                    <input type="button" value="Voltar para o monitoramento" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="javascript: window.location = 'default.aspx';" />
            </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on("ready", function () {
            //$('.chosen-select').chosen(); 
     })
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

O código em c# do back end:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class usuariocadastro : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string IDCliente = "1";
    public string IDPerfil = "1";

    #region SqlConnection Connection and Page Lode
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringSQL"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != Request.Cookies["MPN"]["IDPerfil"])
            IDPerfil = Utils.Cripto.Decrypt(Request.Cookies["MPN"]["IDPerfil"]);

        if (null != Request.Cookies["MPN"]["IDCliente"])
            IDCliente = Utils.Cripto.Decrypt(Request.Cookies["MPN"]["IDCliente"]);

        try
        {


            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //equip.Text = "9999";
                BindGridView();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region show message
    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used for show message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg"></param>
    void ShowMessage(string msg)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + msg + "');</script>");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This Function is used TextBox Empty.
    /// </summary>
    void clear()
    {
        txtLocalizacao.Text = string.Empty;
        txtLocalizacao.Focus();
        txtPorta.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    #endregion
    #region bind data to GridViewEmail
    private void BindGridView()
    {
        try
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Equipamento.IDEquipamento, Equipamento.Localizacao, Equipamento.IDServidor, TipoEquipamento.NomeTipoEquipamento, Equipamento.Porta, Equipamento.EnviarMensagem, Servidor.Endereco FROM Equipamento INNER JOIN Servidor ON Equipamento.IDServidor = Servidor.IDServidor INNER JOIN TipoEquipamento on TipoEquipamento.IDTipoEquipamento = Equipamento.IDTipoEquipamento WHERE (Equipamento.IDCliente = @IDCliente) ORDER BY Equipamento.Localizacao", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCliente", IDCliente);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            GridViewEmail.DataSource = ds;
            GridViewEmail.DataBind();

            lbltotalcount.Text = GridViewEmail.Rows.Count.ToString();

            //equip.ClearSelection();
            //equip.Items.FindByValue(IDCliente).Selected = true;

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Insert Data
    /// <summary>
    /// this code used to Student Data insert in Sql Database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtLocalizacao.Text != "")
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Equipamento (IDCliente,Localizacao,IDServidor,Porta,Atualizar,EnviarMensagem,IDTipoEquipamento) VALUES (@IDCliente,@Localizacao,@IDServidor,@Porta,1,@EnviarMensagem, @IDTipoEquipamento);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);", conn); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCliente", IDCliente);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Localizacao", txtLocalizacao.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDServidor", ddlServidor.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipoEquipamento", ddlTipoEqp.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Porta", txtPorta.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnviarMensagem", chkEnviarMensagem.Checked);
                Int32 intIDEquipCadastrado = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EquipamentoEstadoAtual (IDEquipamento,IDCor,DataHoraAtualizacao) VALUES (" + intIDEquipCadastrado .ToString() + ",4,GETDATE())";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int idequipamento = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoEqp.SelectedValue);

                if (idequipamento == 1)
                { 
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EntradaEstado (IDEquipamento,IDEntradaTipo,IDEntrada, Valor, DataHoraAtualizacao) VALUES (" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,0,0,GETDATE()),(" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,1,0,GETDATE()),(" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,2,1,GETDATE()),(" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,3,0,GETDATE()),(" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,4,0,GETDATE()),(" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,5,0,GETDATE()),(" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,6,0,GETDATE()),(" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,7,1,GETDATE());";

                } else if(idequipamento == 2) { 
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EntradaEstado (IDEquipamento,IDEntradaTipo,IDEntrada, Valor, DataHoraAtualizacao) VALUES (" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,8,0,GETDATE()), (" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,9,0,GETDATE()), (" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,10,1,GETDATE()), (" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,11,0,GETDATE()), (" + intIDEquipCadastrado.ToString() + ",1,12,0,GETDATE());";
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
                //Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
                //ShowMessage("E-mail cadastrado com sucesso!");
                clear();
                BindGridView();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region SelectedIndexChanged
    /// <summary>
    /// this code used to GridViewRow SelectedIndexChanged value show textbox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void GridViewEmail_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridViewEmail.SelectedRow;
        lblIDEquipamento.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        txtLocalizacao.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
        btnUpdate.Visible = true;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Delete Student Data
    /// <summary>
    /// This code used to GridViewEmail_RowDeleting Student Data Delete
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void GridViewEmail_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            int IDEquipamento = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewEmail.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From EquipamentoEstadoAtual where IDEquipamento='" + IDEquipamento + "'; Delete from EntradaEstado where IDEquipamento='" + IDEquipamento + "'; Delete from Equipamento where IDEquipamento='" + IDEquipamento + "';",conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            //Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            //ShowMessage("E-mail deletado com sucesso!");
            GridViewEmail.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGridView();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region student data update
    /// <summary>
    /// This code used to student data update
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string IDEmail = lblIDEquipamento.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update email Set Email=@Email where IDEmail=@IDEmail and IDEquipamento=@IDEquipamento", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtLocalizacao.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDEmail", IDEmail);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDEquipamento", "equip.Text");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            //Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            //ShowMessage("E-mail atualizado com sucesso!");
            GridViewEmail.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGridView(); btnUpdate.Visible = false;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region textbox clear
    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clear();
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Acho que nesse caso o seu código back-end seria melhor para podermos te ajudar. Creio que no front-end não seja interessante fazer esse tipo de validação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que nesse caso o mais interessante é que você faça essa validação da existência de um equipamento já registrado para uma determinada porta no lado do servidor, já que pelo visto essa é uma regra do negócio. Verifique se já existe registrado no banco um equipamento para aquela porta, e se já existir retorne uma mensagem de erro para o usuário.

Você pode até incluir uma restrição UNIQUE na tabela onde você registra esses equipamentos na coluna correspondente à porta, pois assim o próprio banco se encarrega de não permitir que sejam cadastrados dois valores iguais para aquela coluna. Nesse caso, você também teria que tratar os erros que seriam retornados pelo banco.

Mas de toda forma, faça a validação antes de registrar o equipamento. Como disse acima, o que você precisa fazer é característico de regra de negócio, então neste caso é melhor que você previna uma possível exceção se este valor da porta duplicado chegar ao banco. Caso ele chegue, a sua restrição UNIQUE vai apenas impedir que este valor seja efetivamente cadastrado.

Comment: Entendi...vou incluir a restrição UNIQUE no banco. Como eu recuperaria a informação dos erros retornados pelo banco?

Comment: Depende de como está a estrutura do seu projeto. Pelo pouco que vi do seu front-end, você usa WebForms, certo? Se possível, inclua o seu código back-end onde você faz a inclusão do equipamento, fica mais fácil visualizar isso.

Comment: Sim é WebForms. Inclui o código no post!

Comment: Desculpe pela demora. Vi o seu código. Pelo que vi, já está fazendo o tratamento das exceções no bloco do código onde o equipamento é registrado. Isso já trata os casos de exceção se a constraint Unique for "quebrada". Tratar exceções não é a melhor forma de se tratar os erros, mas dê uma pesquisada sobre isso depois pois no comentário não conseguirei explicar.

Comment: Sobre a outra validação: Crie um método que busque no banco de dados os equipamentos que possuem a porta igual ao valor que foi informado pelo usuário no formulário (no caso deve ser só um). Se este método retornar algum equipamento, significa que esse valor já está sendo utilizado para a porta, e portanto não deve ser utilizado de novo. Neste caso então você mostra a mensagem de erro ao seu usuário  (chamando sua função `ShowMessage(ex.Message);` com a mensagem).

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou bastante!